# Python Flask frequently restarts and crashes on Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask

I deployed a web app Microsoft Azure, Linux server, through git. The version of python is 3.8 and I'm using flask. The web app works fine in local, without issues, while on the server it crashes randomly or when a user does a request such as a registration, login etc. It doesn't happen always but in one day there are a lot of crashes and restarts. Seems like there are so many requests that the app crashes, but it's a test application and we're testing it in two or three people. In the logs there are no errors, just frequently restarts.

Comment: It is not possible to answer this without some more detail. You could try adding some error logging to your application to see what is failing.

Comment: I have them and when something is wrong, it always show me the error logs, but with this kind of error, no logs are registered besides the frequent restarts